# Specify database when creating schema

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-schema

I would like to create a schema in a database that is not my current. I tried the following syntax:

```
CREATE SCHEMA MyDatabaseName.MySchemaName
```

and got the error "Incorrect syntax near '.'" So it seems [CREATE SCHEMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx) does not support specifying the database name.

I could do a `USE MyDatabaseName`, but it's complicated since the code I'm writing is inside a stored procedure.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sp_executesql` like so:

```
exec MyDatabaseName.dbo.sp_executesql N'create schema MySchemaName'
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE SCHEMA statement cannot be combined with other statements in the same batch.Separating statements into different batches by adding a GO command after the previous statement should work. Within a stored procedure following query will also work:

```
declare @str varchar(100)
set @str = 'CREATE SCHEMA MySchemaName'
exec (@str)
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I don't really see how this solves my problem... Using `EXEC` I could do a `USE database`, but I'd prefer not to.